# Why is my kitten shedding?

Tags: cats, health, hairloss

I have a 3 month old kitten and I keep finding hair everywhere. He’s really young, so why is he shedding? Have I done something wrong? However, his coat is very shiny and healthy and he’s eating enough. He has been itching lately and his gums are pale. If I can’t do something my mom will sell him.  Please help.

Comment: Welcome to Pets, there might be some underlying medical condition, but all cats - even healthy and young ones - are constantly shedding hair, it is a natural process of hair growth cycle, follicles drop their hair strands and then go dormant for a few weeks or months, then they grow a new strand. What you need to do is to start brushing your cat frequently, so the loose hair strands are collected on the brush instead of being shed on the floor.

Answer (score 3):

I once measured the amount of fur my normal 4,5-5kg cat shed in one week, it was 5,45 grams of medium length fur (it is the amount from the brush I used, so the real amount of fur shed is higher than what I collected).

Kittens will normally start to shed their baby fur at 6-12 months of age, some cats shed more fur in the spring and fall and other cats shed continuously during the year.

For information about shedding in kittens and cats [take a look here](https://be.chewy.com/how-to-manage-your-young-cats-shedding/).

Your cat's itching might be a result of the shedding, so it is normal. If your cat gets bald spots, you need to get it diagnosed and treated by a vet.

A cat's gums are normally light pink; [here is some information](https://www.vetwest.com.au/pet-library/gum-colour-and-your-cats-health) about what the gums can tell you about your cats health.

If your cat changes behaviour, for example stops eating/drinking or hides more, you need to contact your vet.

Answer (score 1):

Perfectly normal, unless the kitten's getting bald spots, then it may be a flea problem. Get the metal bristle pet shed brush for the kitten, it helps so much.
If the kittens gums are pale, that's a sign of worms. So just keep a look out for those. Easy fix though. Over the counter medications work fine if you catch it in time. Is the kitten blooded by chance?

Comment: What do you mean by “blooded”?

Comment: @StephenS I'd also like to know, but I guess that means either "bloody" or "done medical blood tests".